# Increment input Variable Number in shell Script

Tags: awk, sed, replace, numbers, increment

I have a lot script in which it is reading the input parameter. I need to increment all the input parameter by 1. So in case if it 1 it need to be 2 & 2 need to 3 etc. Is there any unix command which can replace this in one go for all scripts instead of going to each scripts and doing it manually. I am new to Unix not sure if there is any way to do it. Below is the example. Appreciate any help on this.

Before Changes

```
#!/bin/ksh
hv_bus_date="CAST('$1' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')"
hv_octs_sys_wid=$2
hv_act_id=$3
```

After Changes

```
#!/bin/ksh
hv_bus_date="CAST('$2' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')"
hv_octs_sys_wid=$3
hv_act_id=$4
```

Comment: Is it possible for those scripts to take more than 9 positional parameters?

Comment: It will be below 10 parameters

Comment: Then I'd go with something like `printf 's/\$%d/$%d/g\n' {1,{2..8}{,},9} | tac | sed -i -f - file1 file2 ...`. Don't try this without backuping inputs though, it's not really reliable

Comment: Hi Oguz, I tried using this on multiple files..it is working. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** To save output into Input_file(s) itself without a GNU `awk`  try following(but make sure you run my 1st solution  to see if output is looking correct).

Let's say we have scripts whose values we need to change.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  83 Dec  8 14:34 file2.ksh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  83 Dec  8 14:34 file1.ksh
```

Our `awk` script's name is `script.ksh` to make sure this script is NOT coming under its own radar :)

```
cat script.ksh
awk '
FNR==1{
  close(out)
  out="out"++count
  rename=(rename?rename ORS:"") "mv " out OFS FILENAME
}
match($0,/\$[0-9]+/){
  before=substr($0,1,RSTART)
  value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH)
  rest=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  if(value<9){
    value++
  }
  print before value rest > (out)
}
END{
  if(rename){
    system(rename)
  }
}
' file*sh
```

Now when we run the above script by doing `./script.ksh` and we can one of the file named `file1.ksh` see its contents have been changed now as follows.

***BEFORE:***

```
cat file1.ksh
hv_bus_date="CAST('$1' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')"
hv_octs_sys_wid=$2
hv_act_id=$3
```

***AFTER:***

```
cat file1.ksh
hv_bus_date="CAST('$2' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')"
hv_octs_sys_wid=$3
hv_act_id=$4
```

---

---

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following, considering that your script names are ending with `.sh` extensions and this will NOT save output into Input_file(s), it will print output on terminal only for you to check output if its coming fine.

```
awk '
match($0,/\$[0-9]+/){
  before=substr($0,1,RSTART)
  value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH)
  rest=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  if(value<9){
    value++
  }
  print before value rest
}
' *sh
```

---

---

***2nd solution(With only newer versions of GNU awk):*** Once you are happy with results of above command and if you have  `gawk` command then try following, this should save output into Input_file(s) itself.  IMHO this needs `gawk` 4.1.0 + version.

```
awk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '
match($0,/\$[0-9]+/){
  before=substr($0,1,RSTART)
  value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH)
  rest=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  if(value<9){
    value++
  }
  print before value rest
}
' *sh
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I tried it by putting the correct file, now it is working..thanks a lot for your prompt response.

Comment: @RameshS, btw thanks for asking this question, I too will make a note of this EDIT program since it does it without GNU `awk` too, cheers.